# Converting a C string to a Pascal-style string

Tags: c, c-strings

I am trying to convert a normal C string into a Pascal string. I am running into trouble when I need to assign the first index of the pascal string to be the length of the string.  I'll place my code below, but I cannot seem to figure out how to convert the length of the original string (especially when it is over 10), slen, into a char that can then be assigned to an index.

```
char pascal[slen];
char pascalFirst = slen + '0';  //Having such a hard time assigning pascal[0]
printf("%c\n", pascalFirst);
pascal[0] = pascalFirst;

printf("%s pasFirst\n", pascal);

for (int i =0 ; i < strlen(pascal); i++){
    pascal[i+1] = s[i];

}
printf("%s\n", pascal);
```

Comment: Why the `+ '0'`? That makes no sense.

Comment: honestly @tadman I saw somewhere else someone did that so I gave it a try.

Comment: `'0'` is the *ASCII value of zero* (48) and shouldn't be there. Don't go down the road of Cargo Cult Programming. If you see someone do something that's where you need to stop, think, and understand what they're attempting before just mimicking what they did. The Pascal string format requires the first byte to be the length *expressed as an `unsigned char`*, not an ASCII value of any kind. Not trying to bust on you here, but C is an extremely unforgiving language and just pasting in arbitrary code can get you into heaps of trouble.

Comment: He is confusing the fact that the first 'char' of the string is not an ascii value for the length, but is the actual number from 0-255.  Easy to do if you don't understand what the first byte actually represents.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I know that it is the actual number, but you cannot assign an index to be an int type in the string.

Comment: Actually, you can.  Just try `char p = 48;` and see if the compiler complains.  You can also typecast if needed when coming from another type to tell the compiler you know you are shortening the type.

Comment: I got it.  Thanks mates

Answer (score 1):

It should be a simple as:

```
char* to_pstr(char* src) {
  char* p = malloc(strlen(src) + 1);

  *((unsigned char*) p) = strlen(src);
  strncpy(src, &p[1], strlen(src));

  return p;
}
```

Where this of course presumes that `src` is <= 255 characters long.

Comment: With the reminder that you need to free that string as it has been dynamically allocated.